# How to handle error using nodejs http module

Tags: node.js, api, express, http

I have two servers. An addUser api in Server1 calls getId api in Server2 using nodejs http module. Below is my code, but I always receive error when addUser tries to parse the data(I don't know if it is error so it has error parsing data) from getId api. If getId api in Server2 returns a normal res.json(), parsing data has no issue. I wonder why getId throw error, the addUser api still goes into on.(data, ...)? What is the right way to handle error in this case?

Server1

```
app.get('/api/addUser/:userName', (req, res) => {
        const options = {
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 3090,
          path: '/api/getId',
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
              accept: 'application/json'
          }
        };
        try {
            const x = http.request(options, function(res){
              let ret;
              res.on('data', function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if (!data) {
                  return;
                }
                const userId = JSON.parse(data); // throw error this line
                const user = {
                  userName: req.params.userName,
                  userId
                };
                ret = user;
                users.push(user);
            });
            }).on("error", err => { console.log(err); }).end();
        } catch (err) {
          errorCounter.add(1);
        }
```

Server2

```
app.get('/api/getId', (req, res) => {
   throw new Error('getId api error');
});
```

Comment: Do you realize that `res.on('data', ...)` receives a chunk of data.  It might be an incomplete chunk and there might be more chunks that are required before it's a whole piece of JSON.  I'd suggest using a higher level http request library such as `got()` or `node-fetch()` will accumulate the whole response for you (add all the chunks together for you) and will even parse the JSON for you if you give it the right options.

Comment: maybe you need to handle this with promise or async/await syntax to your request.

Comment: Do you know what kind of response your `/api/getId` route handler is going to send back to the client?  Maybe your request code should be checking to see what status code you're getting back?  From the standpoint of `http.request()`, this is a successful request, not an error.  It just doesn't have a 200 status code.  A 404 or 500 or whatever status is still a completed http request.  Again, this is all a ton simpler with a higher level library  such as `got()` or `node-fetch()` that checks the status for you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you throw at the top level of your Express request handler (not inside an asynchronous callback), Express will catch that exception and, by default (if you don't have an Express error handler), will turn it into a 500 response status and will send back `text/html` with a summary of the error.  Your attempt to `JSON.parse()` that HTML fails.

Your `http.request()` code needs to check the http status.  At the low level that `http.request()` works, the only way you get an error from `http.request()` is if the actual http request encounters a parameter error or a network failure error.

When the request reaches the server and the server returns ANY kind of response, that is NOT considered an error.  Getting a 404 status or a 500 status back is considered a successful http request from that standpoint of `http.request()`.  If you want 4xx and 5xx status to be considered an error, then you will either have to manually code that or use a higher level library that does that for you.

As such, you have to check the http status that comes back from the response and only try to parse the response IF you get a 2xx response.

In addition, the `data` event is a chunk of data from the response stream.  For small responses on a fast network, it might be the whole response, but it also might be just a chunk of the response.  To do this reliably, you have to accumulate all data from the `data` events and then when the `end` event comes, you now know you have the whole response and you can parse it.

Here's an example:

```
const options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3090,
    path: '/api/getId',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        accept: 'application/json'
    }
};

http.request(options, function (res) {
    let result = "";
    if (res.statusCode < 300) {
        res.on('data', function (data) {
            // accumulate data from the response stream
            result += data.toString();
        }).on('end', () => {
            try {
                const userId = JSON.parse(result);
                // do something with userId here
            } catch (e) {
                // do something with error e here - error parsing JSON
            }
        });
    } else {
        // do something because of a non-2xx status code here
    }
}).on("error", err => { 
    console.log(err); 
    // do something with err here
}).end();
```

Note, you have 3 different places, you need error handling here and 1 place where you have the final response.

As I said in the comments, this is a whole lot simpler with a higher level http library such as `got()` or `node-fetch()`.

Here's how this code looks for `got()`:

```
import got from 'got';

const options = {
    headers: { accept: 'application/json' }
};

got("http://localhost:3090/api/getId", options).json().then(result => {
    // this is your parsed JSON here
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    // got an error here
    console.log(err);
});
```

As you can see, the `got()` library does a lot for you.  It checks the http status.  It parses the JSON.  It combines all the error paths into one error return (a rejected promise).  It takes a URL instead of an options object and the same library call works for https or http URLs.  And, it returns a promise.